# Pyspark condition on date column

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe with two date columns start_date and end_date.
Now I want to get data from df where start_date < today < end_date

I am doing as below -

```
today = datetime.date.today()
df=df.filter(C("start_date")<today & C("end_date")>today))
```

However it throws error as "and" condition is not working on date type.

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems your `closing brackets` are not in right place.

Try with below syntax.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
import datetime
df = spark.createDataFrame([('2023-07-23','2023-07-25'), ('2023-07-24','2023-07-24')], ("start_Date", "end_date"))

today = datetime.date.today()
df=df.filter((col("start_date")< today) & (col("end_date")>today))
df.show(10,False)

#+----------+----------+
#|start_Date|end_date  |
#+----------+----------+
#|2023-07-23|2023-07-25|
#+----------+----------+
```